# SQL statement for displaying unique values

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Below is the data in my table:

```
TABLE:
abc-ac                     
abc-dc                     
aax-i                      
bcs-o-dc                   
ddd-o-poe-dc
```

I need to write a query which will display only the unique entries as a result:

```
abc-ac
aax-i                      
bcs-o-dc                   
ddd-o-poe-dc
```

So basically, since the first two entries start with "abc", it should be treated as one and displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: what define they are the same? the `-` character?

Comment: abc-ac                     
abc-dc

Both the above entries start with abc. So is it possible to just pick one of them?

It can have options such as below:
abc-ac
abc-dc
abc

Comment: I know both start with `abc`, I want to know the logic to say both start the same? the first 3 chars? the chars before first `-`?

Comment: the characters before the first "-"

Comment: So what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not picky about which one of the two `abc-*` records that it shows you can use this:

```
SELECT f1 FROM mytable GROUP BY substring_index(f1, '-', 1)
```

[SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8bcf/4)

That `substring_index()` function will split the value in your field by `-` and return the first bit. So essentially your records get grouped by only the first part. This is one of the few times that we can take advantage of MySQLs strange GROUP BY behavior where it will allow you to leave out non-aggregated fields from the group by.